# Что мешает в json-LD выставить завышенный рейтинг?

Tags: seo

Что мешает в json-LD выставить завышенный рейтинг при помощи aggregateRating ? Зачем он нужен вообще, рейтинг? Если ничего не мешает это делать так через какое то время все будут себе устанавливать максимальный рейтинг.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смысл в том, что не всегда удобно все выводить microdata из-за особенностей html.

- Поэтому, как альтернатива, дается вариант с json-LD что-бы можно генерировать с агрегированных данных.
- Если это страница с рецензией на фильм/ресторан/книгу/авто/гаджет/... 
  там ставится рейтинг не самой странице/сайту, а согласно автору рецензии

+При ручных манипуляциях с рейтингом может быть такой исход:

- Роботы могут автоматически отключить отображение и учитывание микроразметки для данного сайта
- В случае жалобы в службу поддержки могут быть наложены ручные санкции поисковой системы с понижением места в поисковой выдаче

+ссылки по теме от автора вопроса
 https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmaster-ru/FTZ9lo4GmCU

Comment: Так а что мешает мне в ручную поставить любой завышенный рейтинг? И что мешает это сделать другим?

Comment: Ничего. На этот случай у Google и других посковиков есть отличная фраза - они ничего не гарантируют как будет индексироваться/выводится в выдаче. Робот заподозрит накрутку/нелогичную ситуацию - пошлет лесом и, если что - возьмет с других источников - facebook, foursquare, google maps и прочие популярные

Comment: Дополните свой ответ примерно так : Есть вероятность что роботы Google посчитают завышенный рейтинг сфальсифицированным и он перестанет отображаться на снипетах этого сайта в поисковой выдаче, или он применит более жесткие меры в отношении нарушающего сайта.

Comment: Ещ1 это -Согласно документации Гугл вы можете применять разметку структурированными данными для отзыва и оценки: местный бизнес, кинофильмы и книги. Требуется возможность идентификации авторов отзывов, например с линками соц. сетей (Google+) или веб-сайта. В противном случае имеется риск получения санкций за спам в разметке структурированными данными.

Comment: и это - https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/reviews

Comment: И это https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmaster-ru/FTZ9lo4GmCU

Comment: То, что вы написали - верно, но не все тезисы.
К примеру, микроразметку можно внедрять намного шире указанного в руководствах Google, т.к. он ее все-равно будет обрабатывать, но не всегда и во всех регионах выводить (человек-автор сейчас не выводится, событие - не всегда и во всех регионах).
Автоматические санкции пока еще не вводят — такие нарушения не настолько массовые. Ручные санкции есть, но там больше конкуренты abuse'ят, чем сами ловят
Извините, за изначально неполный ответ